# I'm getting an error "module not found " when I'm trying to execute shell commands through a python script

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, subprocess, environment-modules

When the below statement is executed

`out1 = subprocess.run("module load python",shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE , stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)`

This error is generated.

> /bin/sh: module :command not found.

I want to execute shell commands using a python script and this above statement is not working , but when I execute the same statement on the shell then it is working fine and no error is generated.

Comment: Since `module` is not a valid internal command of a POSIX shell (which is what you are running here), an executable with the name _module_ is searched in your PATH, but there obviously is none. Hence the error message.

Comment: So what should I do to make the command working ?

Comment: Put the direcory where your executable named _module_ is located, into your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module` is not an external command but a function to define in the shell/script language used. So to enable the `module` command within a Python script, you need to initialize it with the following code:

```
import os
exec(open('/usr/share/Modules/init/python.py').read())
```

Replace `/usr/share/Modules/init`, by the location where the `python.py` script (from the environment-modules software) is installed on your machine.

Once initialized, you can call the `module` function from your script:

```
module('load', 'modulefile')
```